# Redrawing collection of JButtons in sync

Tags: java, swing

I'm drawing an array of JButtons. 
Calling `setBackground` immediately redraws that button.

The problem is that when calling `redraw` repeatedly, the buttons don't update in sync.

i.e. there's a slight delay between one button being redrawn and another button, on the same pass of `redraw()`.

Is there a way of making all the buttons redraw all together?

I'd appreciate any pointers or suggestions. Thanks.

Note:

- CellButton extends javax.swing.JButton.
- All the buttons are contained in JPanel `grid`.

---

```
final JPanel grid = new JPanel();

Collection<CellButton> cells = new ArrayList<CellButton>();

for(int j=0;j<gridSize;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<gridSize;i++){
        CellButton cellButton = new CellButton(i,j);
        cellButton.setBackground(Color.gray);
        cellButton.addMouseListener(gridListener);
        cells.add(cellButton);
        grid.add(cellButton);
    }
}

...

void redraw(){
    Iterator<CellButton> iter = cells.iterator();
    int x,y;
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        CellButton cellBtn=iter.next();
        x=cellBtn.x();
        y=cellBtn.y();
        cellBtn.setBackground(model.getColor(x,y));
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Is you code executing on the Event Dispatch Thread. Setting the background will only schedule a component for repainting. The RepaintManagers gathers all repaint requests and does them at one time to be more efficient. Repainting is only done on the EDT. So therefore is you change all the properties on the EDT, the buttons should all get repainted at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out if the following works for you.

```
public class ButtonsRedraw {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
final List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    final JButton green = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Green") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        // runs on EDT
        for (final JButton button : buttons) {
            button.setBackground(Color.green);
        }
        }
    });

    final JButton yellow = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Yellow") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        // runs on EDT
        for (final JButton button : buttons) {
            button.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }
        }
    });

    for (int index = 1; index <= 10; index++) {
        buttons.add(new JButton("Button " + index));
    }

    final JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(green);
    buttonPanel.add(yellow);
    for (final JButton button : buttons) {
        buttonPanel.add(button);
    }

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colored buttons");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(buttonPanel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
}
}
```

Basically, the first button changes background colour to green for the ten buttons in the list and the second button changes colour to yellow. Pls note that actionPerformed gets invoked on EDT, which ensures that any component model or component property change gets propagated to the even queue for repainting. Hence, there is no need to call repaint.